# V8 QuickIsUndefined crushes randomly when using IsConstructCall

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

I have a function:

```cpp
auto func = v8::FunctionTemplate::New(context,
    [](const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
        auto isolate = args.GetIsolate();
        if (args.IsConstructCall()) { ... }
        ...
    }).ToLocalChecked();
```

and I exposed this function as following.

```cpp
global->Set(isolate, "func", func);
```

I used the function both as a normal function and a constructor,

```js
func();
new func();
```

and V8 crushed when `IsConstructCall` is called. I found that `IsConstructCall` uses `QuickIsUndefined` to check whether `NewTarget` is `undefined` or not. The problem occurs inside `ReadRawField`, which is called by `GetInstanceType`, and `QuickIsUndefined` calls `GetInstanceType`.

[image: Error in v8-internal.h, line 305]

Since `T=unsigned short`, I added `reinterpret_cast<unsigned short*>(addr)` to the watch and the result was like this, and it was different from what the exception says.

[image]

What makes me more confusing is that sometimes my program runs well without crushing. Instead of `IsContructCall`, I used `v8::Undefined` and `Value::Equals`, and it runs well.

```cpp
!args.NewTarget()->Equals(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), v8::Undefined(isolate)).ToChecked()
```

It seems like `QuickIsUndefined` has some problem, but I can't identify the problem. What may help in this situation? I compiled V8 with MSVC in monolith mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue:
try to compile your code with -DV8_COMPRESS_POINTERS. V8 has compressed pointers as default now.

v8-internal.h "ReadRawField" can help you to understand the background